# How to get php5-fpm to work on LEMP (Nginx, Debian 8 and mariaDB)?

Tags: nginx, mariadb

I was trying to set up a simple **LEMP** server on one of my computers, LEMP being **Nginx**, **Php5-fpm** and **MariaDB**. For a variety of reasons I chose Debian 8 (Jesse).  I've set up LAMP servers before, but not this. All I want to do is test some php scripts offline with the above server combination.

Anyone out there know of a Nginx-Debian 8 example that works with php5-fpm?

I've gone through more than half a dozen Guides, examples from the Nginx wiki, from the documentation, etc.  and I cannot get even get the simple php test file to work.  All I get is the 'Do you want to save or open the file'.
I have the Welcome to Nginx'.  But not the Php!

There are several configurations out there - for Ubuntu, Centos and the one I currently have says it is for Debian, (Jesse) with php5-fpm and MariaDB - which is what I want - but it doesn't work.
I've tried this with and without virtual hosts, using a unix socket or a TCP socket, setting the php.ini file path to both 0 and 1;
I've even completely reloaded Debian Jesse and started all over.

There also seems to be some debate about having to do 'something?' to get Nginx to recognize Php POST calls from scripts, but that's only mentioned once that I came across.

Would it be easier to try to install the LEMP server on Linux Mint 17 - I'm more familiar with that than Debian???
Or Centos 6 or 7 ???

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Congratulations for posting a reasonably well formatted and complete question.  I have highlighted a few keywords, this done by surrounding them with 2 asterisks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same kind of problem after upgrading to Debian 8 (Jesse) and doing some reconfiguration. In my case the solution was to add the "fastcgi_param" line below:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
  try_files $uri =404;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
  include fastcgi_params;
  # Intercepting errors will cause PHP errors to appear in Nginx logs
  fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}
```

/Thomas